# xpath syntax for ignoring whitespace and newlines

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

I'm trying to use xpath on [this page](http://www.meetup.com/ny-tech/members/) to capture the text "past few days" from:

```
<li class="last">
Last visited
<span>


past few days

</span>
</li>
```

I've tried several variants of the xpath expression `'//li[@class="last"]/span/text()'`, as part of:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
visit = tree.xpath('//li[@class="last"]/span/text()')
```

All return nothing.

What is the correct syntax for capturing "past few days"?

Thanks

Comment: When I go to the page you have given I don't see either "Last visited" or "over two weeks ago"...

Comment: Sorry, that was from another, similar page. You should see "past few days". Now fixed. Problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

That page has a default namespace (`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`). You'll either have to register that namespace and use a prefix in your xpath or use `local-name()` (and `namespace-uri()` if there is a possibility of elements from different namespaces having the same local names).

Example of `local-name()`...

```
//*[local-name()="li"][@class="last"]/*[local-name()="span"]/text()
```

*Disclaimer: I don't use scrapy or python. This answer is purely xpath and might not apply 100%.*